# Gridview bind data along with color

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am pulling data from a database and putting the values into an object

```
public class Record
{
 public string Status { get; set; }
 public string Status_Color { get; set; }
}
```

The Status field will contain a string status while the status color contain
a hex color (#ffffff)

Now I want to be able to bind this information to a gridview and I would also like the Status_Color to be set based on the hex value of the string. 
I don't have a problem binding the Status to the gridview. I'm doing something like this this...

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" id="grid">
 <Columns> 
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status"/>
 </Columns>
</Gridview>
```

This finds the status correctly, however i'm not sure how to bind the status_color to this cell?

Would I be binding onrowdatabind event? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the `hex` value of  your property to the `BackColor` value like below:

```
BackColor= '<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Status_Color").ToString())%>'
```

You didn't mention which color so if you want fore color then use the `ForeColor` property:

```
 ForeColor= '<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Status_Color").ToString())%>'
```

For this approach you should use the `ItemTemplate` as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus" Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' ForeColor= '<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Status_Color").ToString())%>'> </asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You can also try to create new property and set value there and just do the setting here as:

```
public string StatusToShow
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Concat("<span style='color:"+Status_Color+"; font-weight:bold'>" Status "</span>");
        }
    }
```

For this approach to work you need to set the `HtmlEncode=False`:

```
 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" HtmlEncode="False"/>
```

Third way of doing this is in the `OnRowBound` event, you can get the control and then set the color in code behind like:

```
 Status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(status_color);
```

Comment: Hey, @Coder of Code I tried the first two of your suggestion. Neither of them worked. When I tried adding the backcolor with BackColor= '<%#....%>' I received a parse error. Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: When I tried setting a field and databind it, I didn't get an error this time ;however, It displayed this in the cell <span style='color:; font-weight:bold'>On Track</span>

Comment: For the second approach you need to set the `HtmlEncode="False"`. I will update the answer.And for the first approach you need to use the `ItemTemplate`.